# IntelliJ IDEA CE sluggish on OS X

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a problem with IntelliJ IDEA CE 2016.2.4 (September 9) being incredibly sluggish on my Macbook Pro Retina (16 GB).

When I'm working on a project (not very big), it keeps lagging between every key I press, and when trying to resolve an issue by clicking `alt+enter`. Auto-complete doesn't actually do me any good as it cannot keep up.

My setup

```
Macbook Pro 15" Retina (Mid 2015)
16 GB RAM
2,5 GHz Intel i7
OSX El Capitan 10.11.6
JDK 1.8.0_102
```

Custom VM Options

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx6g
```

When looking at my activity monitor, it stays at about 1G of memory usage.

I have disabled some plugins that I don't feel is necessary at the moment, but there's still a few that come in handy that I have left enabled.

Do anyone know if it's even possible to get decent performance by adjusting some settings?
If you propose some vm-options, please tell me what the different values actually do (if you know).

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Terribly sorry, I'll try to find another place to post this. If you have a place in mind, please do share @Tobias